# Normal numbers and dense orbit of the shift map

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $b\geq 2$ be an integer and $x\in[0,1[$. Let $T_b(x) = bx\mod 1$. It is known that $x$ is a [normal number with respect to $b$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) if and only if the sequence $(T_b^n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) in $[0,1[$. This fact implies that if $x$ is normal with respect to $b$, then the orbit of x under $T_b$, i.e. the set

$$\operatorname{orb}(x) = \{T_b^n(x):n\in\mathbb{N}\},$$
is dense in $[0,1[$.  Does the converse is true? Or do exist $b$ and $x$ such that $\operatorname{orb}(x)$ is dense, but $x$ is not normal?

The converse of this fact seems not true to me, since the sequence $(\log n\mod 1)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $[0,1[$ but it's not uniformly distributed.

Comment: "dense"  means $x$ is a recurrent point, "normal" means it is uniformly recurret. Not every recurrent number is uniformly recurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every finite length block of base $b$ digits appears in the base $b$ expansion of $x$, the orbit of $x$ is dense in $[0,1[$.  So construct $x$ by enumerating all finite length strings of base $b$ digits, concatenating them with interspersed "spacing" blocks of $0$, and converting the resulting digit string into the real $x$ the usual way.  If you make the intervening blocks long enough, $x$ will fail to be normal.  In base $b=2$, for example, start with the strings

> 0 1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 ...

and take the spacing blocks to be

> 00 00 0000 0000 000000 000000 000000 000000 00000000 ...

that is, of twice the length of the preceding  strings, so the
concatenation is

> 0 00 1 00 10 0000 11 0000 100 000000 101 000000 110 000000 111 000000 ...

which is has way too many $0$s in it to be normal.